# Is using Terraform count ever a good idea?

Tags: terraform, devops, infrastructure-as-code

In order to create multiple resources in terraform, we can use `count` or `for_each`. When we are using count on a list type variable to create multiple resources, terraform will create the state based on an index. If I delete a value in the list located at index somewhere in the middle of the list, all of the next resources will be deleted and recreated (due to the fact that all the next resources after that index are now changing their indexes number).

Since this is true, is there any reason why should I ever use `count` instead of `for_each` (which saves the state based on given key)?

If this is true, it means that I will need to create a key for every resource which I will ever create using a loop. Is this make sense?

It feels like I'm missing the point of count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Terraform `count` [meta-argument](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/count) is not deprecated. It is true that it existed earlier than `for_each`, and doesn't handle deletion of resources as elegantly as `for_each`.

In your case you say you are using `count` to create resources for each item in a list. In the instance where you have a list, set, or map variable representing resources to be created, then `for_each` is definitely the correct thing to use.

However, if there are times you just need `N` number of something, `count` still works just fine. For example if you just had a numeric variable called `number_of_servers`, or if you have a boolean variable called `create_optional_server`, then in either of those cases `count` makes perfect sense and you would have to jump through extra hoops to convert that into something you could pass to `for_each` while not actually gaining any extra functionality from `for_each`.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, looks like count is something legacy.
In my command we moved away from count to the for_each as soon as it became available.
But we still use count for conditions, like enable something, like here:

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account_network_rules" "example" {
      count = var.enabled == true ? 1 : 0
}
```